# Change UIButton border color on highlight

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, colors, uibutton

I've got a simple custom UIButton, to which I added:

```
button.layer.bordercolor = [[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
```

However, I want to change the .bordercolor when the button is highlighted. I tried adding an action to the button's touchDown action that changes the .bordercolor to red, but when the user lifts their finger, it stays red rather than returning to blue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You were on the right track. Check the code below, it elaborates on this, but what you'll want to do is link selectors to different control events on your button. One for `touchDown` to change the shadow to red, and another for `touchUpInside` to change the shadow back when you lift your finger.

Additionally, I see you've asked several questions on Stack Overflow and have yet to mark any as the correct answer. To continue to receive help on this website, you will need to start marking correct answers to your questions.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(highlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(unhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (void)highlightBorder
{
    myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
}

- (void)unhighlightBorder
{
    myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
    //additional code for an action when the button is released can go here.
}
```

**NOTE:** [Other options](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents) for `UIControlEvents` include:

```
enum {
   UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,
   UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,
   UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
   UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
   UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
   UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
   UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
   UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
   UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

   UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,

   UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,
   UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,

   UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,
   UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,
   UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,
   UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,
   UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well if the button receives the touch up inside action, however what if the user were to cancel the touch by dragging their finger off the button? Any idea how I could handle that? Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnWickham sure, there's another touch event called touchDragOutside that would probably do the trick.

Comment: to handle dragging outside, I find that this works: [button addTarget:self action:@selector(unhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];

Comment: To handle dragging outside, use UIControlEventTouchDragExit

Answer (score 17):

The **SWIFT 2.x** answer to your problem:

➜ Just override the highlighted property with "didSet" observer.

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
    didSet {

        switch highlighted {
        case true:
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        case false:
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {

        switch isHighlighted {
        case true:
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        case false:
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lightweight and "swift styled" solution - works great, thanks!

Comment: `if ... else` solution would fit here better. Using `switch ... case` looks to be too complicated :)

Comment: Yeah, don't use case trye/false. Ternary operator is the way to go in these cases (see fethicas answer)

Answer (score 9):

You can override `setHighlighted` and `setSelected` methods in UIButton subclass. From there you just tweak border color like following:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {

    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    [self tweakState:highlighted];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {

    [super setSelected:selected];

    [self tweakState:selected];
}

- (void)tweakState:(BOOL)state {

    if (state) {
        self.layer.borderColor = [_highlightedBorderColor CGColor];
    }
    else {
        self.layer.borderColor = [_defaultBorderColor CGColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4** :

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        layer.borderColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.lightGray.cgColor : UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Self contained solution:

```
static UIColor *BorderColor()
{
  return [UIColor grayColor];
}

static UIColor *HighlightedBorderColor()
{
  return [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

@interface BorderedButton : UIButton

@end

@implementation BorderedButton

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    self.layer.borderColor = BorderColor().CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
  [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
  self.layer.borderColor = (highlighted) ? HighlightedBorderColor().CGColor : BorderColor().CGColor;
}

@end
```

Thanks to @josip-b!

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that doesn't involve subclassing, you could always add an extension method to UIButton. E.g.

```
func setBackgroundColor(_ backgroundColor: UIColor,
                        borderColor: UIColor,
                        borderWidth: CGFloat,
                        cornerRadius: CGFloat,
                        forState state: UIControlState) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    if borderWidth > 0 {
        layer.borderWidth = 0 // hide the layer's border if we're going to draw a border
    }

    context.addPath(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: borderWidth, dy: borderWidth), cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath)
    context.setStrokeColor(borderColor.cgColor)
    context.setFillColor(backgroundColor.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(borderWidth)

    context.closePath()
    context.strokePath()
    context.fillPath()

    let buttonImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, for: state)
}
```

Comment: Just bare in mind you'll need to handle redrawing on bounds changes

Comment: See here for SWFIT button observer syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272274/how-to-change-bordercolor-when-button-ishighlighted