# ImageView in table cell highlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

In my table cell I am having different controls like ImageView, Label, Buttons.

In that ImageView is for UserProfile Image. When the user clicks the ProfileImage it has to highlight.

For that I am using the following code

```
- (IBAction)UserImageClick:(id)sender{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    NSString *strUserID,*strUsername, *strUserProfileImage;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.allPostArray objectAtIndex:[tapRecognizer.view tag]];
    strUserID = [dictionary valueForKey:@"user_id"];
    strUsername= [dictionary valueForKey:@"username"];
    strUserProfileImage = [dictionary valueForKey:@"userprofileimage"];
    [sender setHighlighted:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Is there any way to highlight the sender and animate it? Here the sender is a ImageView.

Comment: I think this may help you , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926729/change-uibutton-border-color-on-highlight

Comment: FYI - do not use `valueForKey:` to get a dictionary value unless you have a specific need to use KVC. Use `objectForKey:`.

Comment: Ok rmaddy I will change it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the color of the border of UIImageView's layer.  Being that UIImageView inherits from UIView, it has a `.layer` property, which is a CALayer.  Something like this...

```
 UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender;

 UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 [imageView.layer setBorderColor:borderColor.CGColor];
 [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
```

Link to the Apple docs for [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)CALayer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
it work for me

_image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

_image.tag = 1;

_image.layer.opacity=0.80;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

if ([touch view] == [_image viewWithTag:1]) 

 {

  _image.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

  _image.layer.opacity=3;

 }
```

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

if ([touch view] == [_image viewWithTag:1]) 

 {     
  _image.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

  _image.layer.opacity=0.80;

}
```

Comment: I think your solution might work, I will check it and get back to you